# Tool to find malformed HTML?

Tags: html

I'm looking for a tool that could help me fix malformed HTML. For example:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">
    <span>Test</span>    
</div>
```

The tool would detect a missing  and inform me the the div with id 'bar' on line 2 is not closed. I know about the w3c validator (using it with the Web Developer Toolbar). But I find the validator tool slow to use. Additionally, once a tag is not closed, the rest of the page generates lots of errors.

This tool can either be a standalone application or a browser plugin.

I'm using Eclipse, JSP, JSTL and jQuery to generate HTML. Even if Eclipse give me some indication on malformed HTML, I have mostly generated code. Therefore, it would be best if the tool analyze the resulting page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTMLTidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) will fix your errors

[xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) will find your errors

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a job for [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Even the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) will find your malformed/unclosed HTML.

I would, as a rule, always be sure to pass my HTML and CSS through their validators, though HTML Tidy is a nice little app to have around too.

Answer (score 2):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249 This firefox extension has done me good as well...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a command line interface, you can use: https://github.com/yaniswang/HTMLHint

It has also its grunt plugin: https://github.com/yaniswang/grunt-htmlhint