# How do you find mismatched tags in HTML?

Tags: html, debugging

I've inherited some rather large static HTML files that need to be fixed up to work in webkit-based browsers, Safari in particular. One of the common bugs I've found that cause rendering differences is missing `</div>` tags. (Both IE7+ and FF3+ seem to ignore these, or make good guesses as to where to close the DIVs, and render as expected.) I'm used to using `vim` with HTML syntax highlighting for editing, but end up writing awk scripts to match starting and ending tags.

What is your favorite tool or technique for matching start and end tags in a large HTML file?

UPDATE: I'm currently in a shop that targets HTML 4.01 Strict, not XHTML.

Comment: I just wonder what Visual Studio would do if you open such a file... Never had this problem myself.

Comment: duplicate: "Tool to find malformed HTML?" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395560/tool-to-find-malformed-html

Comment: @Workshop Alex: Visual Studio does what you'd expect - it highlights all errors with squiggles and puts them into the errors/warnings list. Quite a great tool to manually fix HTML, also if you need to conform to a specific DTD or something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [W3C HTML Validator](http://dev.w3.org/cvsweb/validator/) works fairly well, or if you want something a little simpler then the [Tidy](http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/) FireFox plugin also works.

Comment: THANKS, I just tried out FireFox "HTML Validator" and it is great.  My cravings for simplicity and effectiveness are satisfied.

Comment: No problem, but if you're satisified your question has been resolved, please remember to mark the question as answered.

Comment: @Brandon: I was just waiting a bit to see what other answers came in.

Comment: @system PAUSE, actually I confused you with Smandoli. I thought this was his question, my mistake :P

Answer (score 6):

The [w3c Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) can be (extremely) verbose, but it does check for missing closing tags.

Answer (score 3):

[HTML Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) is a great command line tool.  I often use it with [WGet](http://pages.interlog.com/~tcharron/wgetwin.html)

Answer (score 2):

Most IDE's usually let you know via highlighting, fuzzy-underline or a warning.

Answer (score 2):

[Div Checker](http://www.tormus.com/tools/div_checker#show_div_map) is a great tool that focuses on div tags specifically.

While other tools were only able to tell me that "some tag was missing somewhere".
Div-Checker removes other tags, code, and most comments, to create a clean visual structure of just the divs themselves.
From this div map, it's fairly easy to see if nested divs are correctly paired !
I was able to locate a missing div left out by a wordpress theme developer, with the help of this tool.

Here is the [Posted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17706211/5411817) from @noah-whitmore that enlightened me to this awesome tool.

There are a couple other useful [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16614997/5411817) mentioned in that thread as well, such as [unclosed-tag-finder](http://jona.ca/blog/unclosed-tag-finder) (visually not so easy to read, but helpful if your missing tag is not a div).

Answer (score 1):

vim/gvim & NetBeans both do a great job of tag matching

Comment: I've followed the exact instructions in ":help matchit", but % still doesn't work for me in vim (Cygwin).

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong, you might try this http://www.catonmat.net/blog/vim-plugins-matchit-vim/ or download gvim for Windoze and not go through cygwin.

Comment: @Mike, I've rephrased my complaint as a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440292. Feel free to answer there.

Answer (score 0):

> What is your favorite tool or technique for matching start and end tags in a large HTML file?

A text editor with a built-in XML well-formedness checker, combined with using XHTML for everything.

Comment: Would like to know which ones you favor.

Comment: I used to use one of the plugins for EmEditor on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text with the [Tag plugin](https://github.com/SublimeText/Tag) has a Tag Lint feature which which aims to check correctness of opened and closed tags.

[image]